# How do I translate functions on the Prufer 2-group between functions on the $2^n$ roots of unity and the dyadic fractions modulo 1?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory

> How do I translate functions on the Prufer 2-group between functions on the $2^n$ roots of unity and the dyadic fractions modulo 1?

Let the Prufer 2-group be denoted $\mathbb{Z}(2^{\infty})_2$ and think of it as the dyadic fractions modulo $1$.

And let the Prufer 2-group denoted $\mathbb{Z}(2^{\infty})$ be defined as the $2^n$ roots of unity.

What is the morphism $$\mathbb{Z}(2^{\infty})_2\to\mathbb{Z}(2^{\infty})$$

Additionally, on the dyadic fractions i have the function $\lvert\cdot\rvert_2$ which I need to translate into $\mathbb{Z}(2^{\infty})$

It looks like it's going to be something like $\lvert\cdot\rvert_2\to e^{2i\theta}$ or possibly even $\lvert\cdot\rvert_2\to e^{\sqrt{i\theta}}$

This function has an interesting property on this group; which is *something like* "Measured by this metric, the group contains its own reflection."  Is there some known, precise, statement about this function in relation this group that stands out as interesting?  I am imagining this statement may be related to the concept of the Pontyragin dual but that may be way off.

A slightly descriptive answer is likely to be more useful to me than one only in algebra.

Comment: I intend to award this bounty to Torsten. Perhaps the bounty will also draw others' attention to his exemplary answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are asking for an *iso*morphism

$$f: (\Bbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]/\Bbb{Z}, \; +) \simeq (\mu_{2^\infty}(\Bbb{C}), \; \cdot)$$

(left hand side: dyadic fractions modulo 1, right hand side: all $2^n$-th roots of unity in $\Bbb{C}$)

No big deal. Try the most obvious one defined by
$$f:\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^n} +\Bbb{Z} \mapsto exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{2^n}\right).$$

(There are others: $$f_k = \displaystyle \frac{1}{2^n} +\Bbb{Z} \mapsto exp\left(k\frac{2\pi i}{2^n}\right)$$
works for every odd $k$ ($f$ is just $f_1$), actually it works for every $k \in \Bbb{Z}_2^*$. Try $k=3$ to see what happens. This is the actual place where the Pontryagin dual makes its entrance.) <sub>See "Added" below for more detail.</sub>

As for "translating", I assume you want to pull the $2$-adic absolute value on the LHS over to the RHS. Formally, you define $|\cdot|'_2$ on $\mu_{2^\infty}(\Bbb{C})$ via $|\xi|'_2 := |f^{-1}(\xi)|_2$. Again, nothing spectacular happens:
$$|\xi|'_2 = 2^n \Leftrightarrow \xi \text{ is a }primitive \:2^n\text{-th root of unity}.$$

**Added**: To say a bit more about the "$k$" above. For every $r\in \Bbb{Z}$, one has an endomorphism of the group to itself $x \mapsto rx$ (on the LHS) resp. $x\mapsto x^r$ (on the RHS). So far that is true for any abelian group. Now it turns out that in this case, one can even take $r$ from the much bigger set of $2$-adic integers $\Bbb{Z}_2 \supsetneq \Bbb{Z}$. Namely, this still makes sense because for each $x$ in the LHS (resp. RHS) there is some $n$ such that $2^nx = 0$ (resp. $x^{2^n} =1$), so to multiply (resp. exponentiate) that $x$ with $r\in \Bbb{Z}_2$ is just defined to be the same as $r'x$ (resp. $x^{r'}$) for an $r' \in \Bbb{Z}$ with $r' \equiv r$ mod $2^n$. One finds that all endomorphisms of the group are of that kind,

$$End(\Bbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]/\Bbb{Z}) = Hom(\Bbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]/\Bbb{Z}, \Bbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]/\Bbb{Z}) \simeq \Bbb{Z}_2 \qquad (*)$$

This is (a version of) Pontryagin duality.

Now, not all those endomorphisms are bijective (=automorphisms). In fact, exactly the ones with $r\in \Bbb{Z}_2^*$ are. (In fact, the identification (*) is a *ring* isomorphism, where composition in $End(\Bbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]/\Bbb{Z})$ corresponds to multiplication in $\Bbb{Z}_2$.) Whereas for $r \notin \Bbb{Z}_2^*$, the map $x \mapsto rx$ (resp. $x\mapsto x^r$) is *not injective*. Fun exercise: Find the kernel for $r=2^n$. Look at the example $r=2$. Second fun exercise: On the RHS, the endomorphism corresponding to $r=-1$ does the same as complex conjugation.

That all being said, we now have that for each $k\in \Bbb{Z}_2^*$, the map $\alpha_k: x \mapsto kx$ (resp. $\beta_k: x\mapsto x^k$) is a group automorphism -- i.e. an isomorphism of the group to itself -- on the LHS (resp. RHS). Now of course composing an isomorphism with an automorphism of the domain or codomain gives an isomorphism again. Now just notice that the above $f_k$ is nothing else than

$$ f_k = f\circ \alpha_k = \beta_k \circ f.$$

Final note: All this works, mutatis mutandis, if one replaces $2$ by any prime $p$. Also compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/178771/96384 for the $p$-free version.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was looking for the **Group Isomorphism** but didn't want to say the wrong thing. I would ask how the group operation translates but it seems you're saying addition in the dyadic fractions modulo $1$ is congruent to multiplication in the $2^n$th roots of unity.  All looks fairly intuitive.  The 2nd bit you say; "There are others..." Hold that thought. I think this may allow for some form of induction. I think if we set $k=2^{2p-1}$ or something like that; am I right in thinking this enables us to map the group back onto to itself? Is this what makes it fail to be Noetherian?

Comment: Yes, it's a group iso from the additive LHS to the multiplicative RHS. I edit to expand a little bit on the $k$. -- What makes it fail to be Noetherian is that there are infinite ascending chains of subgroups, e.g. in the LHS $\frac{1}{2}\Bbb{Z}/\Bbb{Z} \subsetneq \frac{1}{4}\Bbb{Z}/\Bbb{Z} \subsetneq \frac{1}{8}\Bbb{Z}/\Bbb{Z} ...$ (which via the iso translates to: 2nd roots of unity $\subsetneq$ 4th roots of unity $\subsetneq$ 8th roots of unity ...)

Comment: I can't get around thinking $f$ should be $f\left(\dfrac{n}{2^q}\right)=exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi i\cdot n}{2^q}\right)$ but that doesn't seem to correspond with what you put... but I may just be struggling to follow your notation.

Comment: That's what the $f$ in my post does. I only wrote it for (in your notation) $n=1$ because for general $n$ this follows from $f$ being a group homomorphism.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm glad that's the case for my understanding of the problem but sorry for my inability to decipher good maths writing :(